# Vuetify - Center content in v-list-tile-content

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to center the content inside a **v-list-tile-content** of a **v-list** without success.
I've tried to apply text-xs-center, justify-center to the **v-list** element and the **v-list-tile-content** and it does not work.
Also I've tried to put a div inside the **v-list-tile-content** and apply the previously mentioned classes.
I've found that the v-list-tile-content element has a **align-items: flex-start** and if I delete that it automatically apply the classes.

As far as I know align-items it's for vertical alignment and for horizontal alignment the proper class is justify-items, am I right?

```html
<v-list class="table pa-0">
    <v-list-tile
        v-for="(element, index) in elements"
        :key="`pricing_table_element_${index}`"
        :class="{'dark-background': index % 2 === 0}"
        avatar
    >
        <v-list-tile-avatar>
            <fa-icon
            icon="check-circle"
            color="#00BB9B"
            />
        </v-list-tile-avatar>

        <v-list-tile-content>
            {{ element.content }}
        </v-list-tile-content>

        <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-tooltip right>
                <fa-icon
                    slot="activator"
                    icon="info-circle"
                    color="#f68e28"
                />
                <span>{{ element.tooltip }}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
        </v-list-tile-action>
    </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I wanted to use the Vuetify native classes but they had not the !important and the **align-items: start** of the v-list was overwriting my aling-center, I just added an inline style as follows:

```html
<v-list-tile-content
  :style="{
    'align-items':'center'
  }"
>
  {{ element.content | capitalizeFirstLetter }}
</v-list-tile-content>
```

This was the solution that I was searching for. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use all of these CSS rules on one of the Vuetify [example list codepens](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#avatar-with-title-and-action), it aligns the list item text center. (If you don't have a [second line](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#icon-with-2-lines-and-action), you don't need the `flex-direction: row` part.)

```
.v-list__tile__content{
    justify-content: center!important;
    flex-direction: row!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
}

.v-list__tile__title, .v-list__tile__sub-title {
    text-align: center!important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but only for text. Is there a way to bring the arrow icon from Nested lists to also align center?

Comment: it looks like the class name for that is `.v-list__group__header__append-icon`, or the parent class `.v-list__group__header` might help. If those don't work, just try right clicking and "inspecting" all the components [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#expansion-lists) and testing CSS rules in the Elements tab of the Chrome Inspector?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for

> v-list-item-component

to center a component in a v-list-item in vuetify versions > 2 as given on [justify content with vuetify flex](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex)

```
<v-list-tile-content
class="d-flex justify-center"
>
  {{ element.content }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-list-tile-content` has `flex-direction: column`

This means that you have to set `align-items: center` to horizontally center the content within.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ element.content }}` inside `<v-list-tile-content>` that's just a text, I suppose. Therefore, simply adding `class="text-center"` should work. I've had very similar issue with `<v-list-item-title>` and `<v-list-item-title class="text-center">` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

just add a class of `"text-center"` to the `<v-list>`.

it should be like this :
`<v-list class = "text-center">`

Comment: Do you sure in this answer? 
Maybe you mean `justify-center` class?